# asp.net calendar control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, calendar, controls

I add a simple calendar control in my asp.net page, but i can't change month. Links prev/next month don't work ...

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px"
    DayNameFormat="FirstTwoLetters" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" ShowGridLines="True" 
    NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth"
    CellPadding="0"  
    OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" >
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="LightGray"></OtherMonthDayStyle>
</asp:Calendar>
</form>
```

Help please ^^
thank's

P.S. It's not a date picker, it's an event calendar ...

Comment: By any chance do you have any code behind? Maybe setting the current date?

Comment: You have given NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" so month name will appear instead of "Next" and "Prev" links; but I think it won't prevent you from navigating through previous and next month. If you want to show "Pev" & "Next" text you have to set the properties likeNextMonthText="Next" and PrevMonthText="Prev"

Comment: Yes I know, but when i click on the next month, the link don't work.

Maybe the javascript function postBack don't work ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your Calendar1_DayRender code look like? Are you trying to set a default date? If so, are you only doing it if !IsPostBack ? I put this code in a test page and it works just fine.